# how can i make this jQuery scroll smoothly to the div i am targeting

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

```js
$(function() {
  $('#exampleModal').modal({
    show: true,
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static',
  });
  
  $('.workbook_link').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#cardworkbook").position().top - 100
    }, 1000);
  });
  
  $('.workbook_link').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#mainworkbook").offset().top
    }, 500);
  });

  $('.about_tool').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.about_section_area').offset().top
    }, 500)
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code should already scroll smoothly. The fact you've bound two competing event handlers to the `.workbook_link` element won't be helping though, and may well be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i need to use the event handler two times first when there is no data second when data is added so, there are different buttons for these 2 scenarios.

Comment: In that case you need to change your logic so that only one is bound, and you use conditional logic within that event handler to execute ***one*** of the `animate()` calls, not both. We can't help with that as there's not enough information in the question

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the animation time from 1000ms to 10ms it worked for me, with 1000ms it was a little jerky at start, after using 10ms it scrolled at uniform speed.